2017-12-23: On the first day of Christmas break, my mods gave me…
A nice little Christmas cleanup:

Retagged all questions with untagged
Renamed deterministic into deterministic-wallets
Added tag info to private-key-export, fragmentation, inventory, transaction-capacity, proof-of-stake
Burninated formatting because it was used for address formats and for questions about backups before formatting a hard drive.
Merged address-shortening into address-format
Renamed future to futures, added tag info, removed it from all questions referring to developments that may still come to pass, added future-proof where applicable.
Merged scaling into scalability, created synonym
Merged installing into installation, created synonym
Created utxo-set.
Burninated video, because it was used for gpu-mining and to inquire about a viral video.
Burninated reporting as it was only on five questions that were concerned with five different topics.
Merged ppcoin into peercoin, created a synonym
Burninated conversion


Also merged PPCoin into peercoin and created synonym :)

@MeshCollider: Added it. :)

Impressive cleanup though Murch, thank you!
